# Move baked physics simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

I just simulated and baked a fire simulation and was wondering if I could somehow move the fire somewhere else. When I move the emission object now, the fire stays behind.

I understand if there's no way to do this, but any help would be appreciated!

[image]